# T-SQL - Extracting Surname from one column of data

Tags: t-sql

I have a column that writes back a full name in one string: "Mr John Smith".

How do I extract just the surname?

My column name is "Contact_Name".

The data source contains thousands of names, some will have a hyphen. There will always be a space between first and second name.

Thanks

Comment: This is notoriously  difficult problem, as the number of different ways unconstrained users can enter individuals names, is almost unlimited. Better solution: separate firstName, prefix, middleName, surname, title, suffix, etc. into separate fields and then clean up your data during migrate to new schema.

Comment: Agree with Charles, how are you going to handle people that have double-barrelled or even simply multi-part surnames?  Can you 100% guarantee that your data *always* has a surname?

Comment: Is the surname always last (after last space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not catch all the potential Surnames, but will do what you are asking in your question:

```
declare @Contact_Name nvarchar(100) = 'Mr John Smith';

select reverse(left(reverse(@Contact_Name)
                   ,charindex(' ',reverse(@Contact_Name),1)-1
                   )
              ) as Surname;
```

Returns:

````````
Surname
```````
Smith
````````

Answer (score 0):

If your Contact_Name contain space every time, this should give you a relative good solution.

```
SELECT REVERSE('ad bbb cvb'),
CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('ad bbb cvb')),
 LEN('ad bbbb cvb'),          
SUBSTRING('ad bbb cvb', 
          LEN('ad bbb cvb')-CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE('ad bbb cvb'))+2,
          LEN('ad bbb cvb'))
```

Comment: Have you tested this?  It returns 'h' for the `Contact_Name` of 'Mr John Smith'

Answer (score 0):

Wow, some of these answers are super complicated...Here's a simplified version:

```
DECLARE @NAMES TABLE (Name VARCHAR(55));
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Mr. John Smith');
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Mrs. Jane Smith');
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Mr. John Doe');
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Mr. Englebert Humperdink');
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Ms. Maybe Happy-NotSoMuch');
INSERT INTO @NAMES VALUES ('Mr. Lovely Taco');

SELECT RIGHT(Name,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Name)) - 1)
FROM @NAMES
;
```

Returns:

```
Name
-----
Smith
Smith
Doe
Humperdink
Happy-NotSoMuch
Taco
```