# T-SQL - How to match two names from different tables within a substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns that write back data and are stored in a databox

```
Contact_Name: "Mr John Smith" - Databox 1
Group_Name: "Mr J Smith" - Databox 2
```

Both names are in one string and cannot be separated.

I need to verify that the Surname stored in both databoxes match.

The data source contains thousands of names, some will have a hyphen. There will always be a space between first and second name.

Comment: I can suggest you to sanitize your data. If you can create an "standart" so mathcing strings will be much easier. Of course for your example I can write that name in dozen different ways

Comment: What is a databox?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is take the answer from your previous question here: [T-SQL - Extracting Surname from one column of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417488/t-sql-extracting-surname-from-one-column-of-data) and then store that `surname` value alongside the rest of the record.  You can then compare from there with a simple equality:

```
select case when Contact_Name_Surname = Group_Name_Surname
            then 'Match'
            else 'No Match'
            end as DoTheSurnamesMatch
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I have two surnames in the group? Example: Mr A Smith and Mr P James but the Contact is Mr Smith and I want to match those. Will the above work for this?

Comment: @user114790  Then you are well into the realms of fuzzy matching (as `Mr P Smith and Mrs S Smith` are not both the same person as `Mr K Smith`) and you will have a better return on your time investment if you actually sort out your data as it comes in.  Why are you even trying to work with data in this format?

Answer (score 0):

To isolate the surname/last-name from both inputs, you can use a combination of 3 functions: substring, reverse and charindex.

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE('MR JOHN SMITH'),1,CHARINDEX(SPACE(1),REVERSE('MR JOHN SMITH')))
```

results in 'HTIMS'

Although the result is the reverse of the surname, its fine for comparison

This could be worked into a function for easy comparison of the Contact_Name and Group_name inputs

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_compare_names (@Contact_Name AS VARCHAR(100),@Group_Name AS VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @is_match AS INT = 0
    DECLARE @sub_contact_name AS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @sub_Group_Name AS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @first_contact_space AS INT 
    DECLARE @first_group_space AS INT
    SET @first_contact_space = CHARINDEX(SPACE(1),REVERSE(@contact_name))
    SET @first_group_space = CHARINDEX(SPACE(1),REVERSE(@Group_Name))
    SET @sub_contact_name= SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@contact_name),1,@first_contact_space)
    SET @sub_Group_Name = SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Group_Name),1,@first_group_space) 

    IF @sub_contact_name= @sub_Group_Name
        SET @is_match = 1
    ELSE
        IF @Group_Name LIKE '%' + REVERSE(@sub_contact_name) + '%'
            SET @is_match = 1
        ELSE
            SET @is_match = 0
    RETURN @is_match

END
```

You could run it in a select statement as follows:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_compare_names('Mr John Smith','Mrs J Smith')
```

It should also work for a group_name with 2 names:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_compare_names('Mr John Smith','Mr J Johnson and Mrs J Smith')
```

or use it in tsql code with variables:

```
DECLARE @Contact_Name AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Mr John Smith'
DECLARE @Group_Name AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Mr J Smith'

IF dbo.fn_compare_names(@contact_name,@Group_Name) = 1
    --Do something
    PRINT 'It matched'
ELSE
    --Do something else
    PRINT 'It did not match'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--  dummy data
;WITH [data] AS (
    SELECT
         [databox1] = N'Mr John Smith'
        ,[databox2] = N'Mr J Smith'
)
--  end dummy data
SELECT 
     [databox1]         =   [databox1]
    ,[databox2]         =   [databox2]
    ,[is_surname_same]  =   CASE WHEN   RIGHT([databox1], CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), REVERSE([databox1]))) 
                                    =   RIGHT([databox2], CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), REVERSE([databox2]))) 
                                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                            END
FROM 
    [data];
```